# PHP: Update database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this to update the messages table in my database, and set the message_read cell to 1.

But I can't get it to work. It always says 0 where it supposed to change to 1.

I'm pretty sure the variables are right.

```
$q = "UPDATE messages SET message_read='1' WHERE id='$messageid' AND to_user='$usermsg'";
mysql_query($q);
```

I do not get any errors either.

"usermsg" = the session username
"messageid" = the id of the message

Comment: Just making sure... you are connecting to mysql and selecting the proper database first, right?

Comment: Are you escaping the values in `$messageid` and `$usermsg`?  Are you certain that such a row even exists in the database?

Comment: Yes, i included the connect file with the right database.

Comment: What is the type of message_read collumn ? If it's INT, BIGINT,TINYINT etc. try this : `... SET message_read=1 WHERE ...`

Comment: No, i am not escaping the variables. Yes, the row exists.

Comment: Then you have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Please look up this term and use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to process the user-supplied values you intend to use in your query.

Comment: Its an INT, and i tried seting just 1 without the '', still not working.

Comment: Okay, i will look that ut cdhowie :)

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the generated query (`echo $q`) and running it yourself in the mysql monitor?

Comment: No i have not tried that, i can try that now and see what happens

Comment: @cdhowie TIL. After some Googling I have removed that answer and humbly admit your correctitude.

Comment: UPDATE messages SET message_read=1 WHERE id='' AND to_user='kaizokupuffball'   

I see now that the message ID is not showing

Comment: Solved! :) Thx for all response!

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball: You should post how you fixed the problem as an answer and accept that answer, so that people viewing the question can see what the problem was.

Comment: Problem was that i forgot an underscore in the variable. Typo big time.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball: I mean you should enter this information into a new answer below, then mark it as accepted.  Not everyone is going to read the comments on the question; they are going to look for an answer with a green checkmark.

Comment: Cannot answer before 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = "UPDATE messages SET message_read='1' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($messageid)." AND to_user='".mysql_real_escape_string($usermsg)."';";

$result = mysql_query($q);

if(!$result)
{ 
    die( mysql_error() ); 
}
else
{
    echo 'Number of affected rows:'.mysql_affected_rows();
}
```

If there was something wrong with your query you will be able to see the error printed on screen. And if not you can see how many rows were affected by the query.

I've also added some SQL injection projection just in case.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the correct syntax:

```
$q = "UPDATE messages SET message_read = 1 WHERE id = ".$messageid." AND to_user='".$usermsg."'";
```

Don't use quotes when the field type is INT.

Comment: -1 MySQL will convert strings to numbers implicitly, as appropriate.